# How do we pass record's page as a link in apex class?

Tags: apex, email, custom-link

I have one apex class somehow i need to populate a link. That link should be open records detail page.

This is what i've given in Email Templete. Whenever i send a mail through this Templete i can see a link in email
that is opening Record's page. Same like i need it in Apex class.

Please review the FCPA changes for {!Question_Answer__c.Account__c}. 
{!Question_Answer__c.Link}

[image]

This mail is generated by email template. Same like i need it through That class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this easily in Apex. 
create `Pagereference` method

```
public pagereference redirectUser()
{
    return new pagereference('/'+recid);
}
```

and call this method and it will redirect to record detail page. You can do something like

```
String Recordlink = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+RecordId;
```

and this a same link which you are getting in email. You can display it on VF page or pass it to any other method.

Comment: @chris so from that method you want to redirect to detail page?

Comment: @chris check my updated answer.

Comment: @chris this question has accepted answer. Please post a new question and then notify me in comments.

Comment: Hi Tushar Sharma Please check this URL http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129330/how-to-send-email-with-only-modified-records